# Microsoft Bot Framework object model

Tags: .net, botframework

Where can I get pictorial representation of Microsoft Bot Framework object model. The diagram which represents all the objects and relationship in them at one place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the official Bot Framework documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/index-bf-sdk?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). If they've released an object model, it will be in those pages.